# Why mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps are not just one function in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Could someone explain to me what are the reasons why **Redux** has two functions `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` that both add props to a container?

Definitions:

> **mapStateToProps** is a utility which helps your component get updated
>   state (which is updated by some other components)
>
> **mapDispatchToProps** is a utility which will help your component to fire
>   an action event (dispatching action which may cause change of
>   application state)

Why Redux team chose to break it into two mapping functions - i.e. why not have just one function mapToProps(state, dispatch, props) that do both?

- Is it just separation of concerns / easier to understand reason?
- Is it because of performance issues with re-binding in `mapDispatchToProps` that creates new functions for every change? Having separate function for action creations bindings will help to avoid this extra job? Considering that  `mapStateToProps` is called on every state change.

**Example:**

```
const increaseAction = { type: 'increase' }

class Counter extends Component {
  render() {
    const { value, onIncreaseClick } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{value}</span>
        <button onClick={onIncreaseClick}>Increase</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onIncreaseClick: () => dispatch(increaseAction)
  }
```

}

See this [Redux example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6xkoy43vqw)

Comment: The author of Redux Dan Abramov explains [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJ38wSFbM3A&feature=youtu.be&t=2455) that `mapDispatchToProps` allocates functions for every action creator that is a very costly operation to redo when you have a lot of components. It looks like there are two different mechanisms that detect when redux needs to update the state and action creator bindings - therefore two different functions: `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`. Is this the answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Andrey Prokhorov is right, and it's funny you asked. I found myself in the bowels of github issues earlier today and found this issue ([Add `state` as the third parameter to `mapDispatchToProps`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/237#issuecomment-168818326)). While the title doesn't seem to relate, if you dig through the comments, gaearon (the creator of react-redux) explains:

> Please take a look at [#1](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/1). This option has been considered and
>   rejected. Yes, it's very bad for performance to re-bind action creator
>   on every dispatch, which is what will happen if we let people access
>   the state in the same place they bind action creators. Technically
>   they can still do it now with mergeProps but it's hidden well enough
>   that people who aren't experienced with Redux don't discover it by
>   mistake.

I also linked to the very first issue that gaearon linked to for react-redux where it was discussed (it was literally issue #1 on github for react-redux). I'm sure they COULD change it to the way you describe, but I think gaearon's comment sums it up:

> The goal of this library is to encourage performant patterns because
>   otherwise people will say “Redux is slow!” even if the cause is their
>   suboptimal function binding code. We don’t want this to happen, so
>   we’d rather make certain unperformant cases harder to implement.

Comment: Usually, creators of libraries try to abstract away how the library code is actually working i.e. hide implementation details such as the difference between how redux state and dispatched actions turn to props of a component. This is not the case for Redux. Thanks for your comment, the reason turns to be an educational purpose! It is a pity that not so many are actually thinking about such implementation, this question got less than 100 views during first 2 weeks after I asked :)